# Cannot run OTN Developer Day VM in Oracle VM to get to work with Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, installation, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I want to install and run Oracle DB for training purposes. For this I've installed the Oracle VM and got some VM templates to run on the VM:

1. [Oracle VM Manager 3.2.4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/vm/overview/templates-101937.html)
2. [Oracle OTN Developer Day](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html)

But the first one turned to be just VM Manager giving no access to the work with DB.

As I launch the second one it gives the issue `Failed to open session for VM...`, problem lies in USB 2.0 device controller being not found.

[image: implementation of usb 2.0 controller is not found]

How to fix those problems?

Is there a simple way to install and run testing purposes Oracle DB under Windows (Win 8.1).

Comment: Have you tried to follow suggested steps in the error message? They are pretty straightforward. Do you have problems with installing `Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack`?

Comment: Thank you, i've installed VM VB Extention Pack. Now it works fine, still cannot lay hold of Oracle DB and SQL Delveloper working in them. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442814/i-cannot-find-a-hint-on-oracle-sql-developer-and-oracle-database-12c-inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on your "Oracle OTN Developer Day" and select "Settings", then go to "USB" tab and clear the "Enable USB Controller".

Answer (score 0):

you can fix this by installing “virtualBox Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack” https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads