# i cannot find a hint on 'Oracle SQL Developer' and 'Oracle Database 12c' inside Linux shell

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to run 'Oracle Database 12c' for training purposes, but as i've installed 'Oracle OTN Developer Day'(Linux 6 works) i cannot find a hint on 'Oracle SQL Developer' and 'Oracle Database 12c' inside this Linux shell?
In docs on '[Oracle OTN Developer Day](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html)' i find its contents:

- Oracle Linux 6.5
- Oracle Database 12c Release 1 Enterprise Edition
- Oracle XML DB
- Oracle SQL Developer
- Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler
- Oracle Application Express
- Hands-On-Labs (accessed via the Toolbar Menu in Firefox)

Where (what folder) to seek for them?
Should i manually install 'Oracle Database 12c' and 'Oracle SQL Developer' above it?
How to make db run and have SQL Developer connected to it?

### UPDATE

picture of initial window in Linux: (no Sql Developer there):
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I can not find a hint on Oracle SQL Developer"? I've installed this pre-built VM without issues, the icon for SQL Developer appears on the Linux desktop.

Comment: DB is autostarted, SQL Developer shortcut is on the desktop. Username and password is `oracle` as said in the article you linked to.

Comment: In my case the icon does not transpire (see a picture in Update).

Comment: @Yaroslav, you said DB is autostarted. Not bad, still how to get hold of SQL Developer (see image in update)?

Comment: @IgorSavinkin You're logged in as root. I'd bet the documentation tells you that you should login as user oracle instead.

Comment: @IgorSavinkin Yes @FrankSchmitt is right, you have to login as user `oracle`.

Comment: @IgorSavinkin There is a useful document: [Learning Oracle with Oracle VM VirtualBox Whitepaper](http://blogs.griddba.com/2012/06/my-collaborate-12-presentations.html).

Comment: Thank you for help @FrankSchmitt. It now works. You might make your comment as an answer for my approval. But now i'm puzzled of how to import the sample Oracle HR database into SQL Developer (and in DB if not present there)? The link i've found is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059081/how-do-you-import-the-sample-oracle-hr-database-into-sql-developer?rq=1
Is that solution applicable to this package?

Comment: @IgorSavinkin I've added an answer. Regarding the HR schema: Usually, when you setup a new database instance, the Installer asks you whether you want to install example data - this includes the SCOTT and HR schemas. Whether this image includes these example schemas, I cannot tell - try connecting to the database (e.g. as SYS), run a `select username from dba_users`, and check whether the output contains HR and SCOTT. If not, you might want to aks in the forum for the image, http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=823

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're logged in as root. You should login as user oracle instead.